# Tools for checking Spectre (both variants) system vulnerabilities on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, security

I seek some reliable ways / tools for checking Spectre (both variants) system vulnerabilities on Windows 10? That are the following CVEs:

- [CVE-2017-5754](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2017-5754) [rogue data cache load]
- [CVE-2017-5715](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2017-5715) [branch target injection]

I would like to have more than one option, if there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ## SpecuCheck (portable executable, CLI)

   [Website (GitHub)](https://github.com/ionescu007/SpecuCheck); [Download page](https://github.com/ionescu007/SpecuCheck/releases)

   Example image on my computer (green means, you're doing OK):

   [image: SpecuCheck CLI]
2. ## SpeculationControl (PowerShell module, CLI)

   [Website (Microsoft - Technet) + Download page](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Speculation-Control-e36f0050)

   Example image on my computer (green means, you're doing OK):

   [image: SpeculationControl - PowerShell]
3. ## InSpectre (portable executable, GUI)

   [Website (GRC) + Download page](https://www.grc.com/inspectre.htm)

   Example image on my computer (green means, you're doing OK):

   [image: InSpectre GUI]